# Ability to search through a list to match words with letters in specific position

Tags: string, list

Currently the game randomly selects a word from a dictionary which is stored in a list and the game functions perfectly as to how I want it.

The next step I am trying to do is a mode where the game has the ability to cheat by searching through the list of words in the dictionary and changing the word which the player has to guess with another word. The roadblock I have hit is that if the player has already guessed some letters, the word can only be changed with words which contain letters in the same positions.

For example if the selected word to guess was: "Clock" and the player had already guessed the letters "L", "O", and "K" the only option would be to change the word with another word with those letters in the same position (e.g. "Block".)

This is where I am stuck and would like to know if there's a way to search the list for words containing the letters in the positions of the guessed letters.

Many thanks.

Comment: How is this "cheating"?  From the player's perspective, nothing has changed.  The game has answered honestly to all player input, and the outcome of the game will not change if the game decides the word is Block rather than Clock.

Comment: No, not unless the game lies to the player.  If the game never lies, the word the computer ultimately picks does not matter.  But try it out and see if it's harder or not :-)

Comment: @EricJ. I think the comment by the asker says the program "lies". If the program knows both "Clock", "Block", "Flock", etc. match, and if the player spends one guess at "Clock", and the program only eliminates "Clock" *after* the player made the guess, that would be cheating (and make the game harder to win than if the program had committed itself to one word from the very onset).

Comment: Yes @Jeppe-Stig-Nielsen that's correct.

Comment: Oh I see... the player doesn't just fill in letters, but explicitly guesses "Clock" before the letters are filled in.  Makes sense.

Comment: But even if the player only guessed individual letters, it would still matter. E.g. if there was one last letter missing and *n* possible words, the player would be guaranteed to fail *n-1* times before guessing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to approach this with a regular expression.

Replace each unguessed character with '\w', then using Linq you'd have something like this:

```
    private List<string> FindPossibleWords(string guess, List<string> words)
    {
        Regex rg = new Regex(guess); //must have replaced unknowns with '\w'
        return words.Where(w => rg.IsMatch(w)).ToList();
    }
```

So, for example, you would call this method with the string "\wlo\wk" and the list of words (your "dictionary").

This would then return a list of possible matches. Which one you choose is then up to you.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you have an index and a char, like

```
int index = 3;
char c = 'c';
```

you can filter the dictionary this way:

```
List<string> filtered = words.Where((str => str.ElementAtOrDefault(index) == c)).ToList();
```

for example:

```
List<string> words = new List<string> { "Block", "Clock", "Work", "Orange" };

List<string> filtered = words.Where((str => str.ElementAtOrDefault(index) == c)).ToList();
```

`filtered` contains only "Block" and "Clock". If you have several such requirements you can chain the `Where` clauses accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you start with a dictionary of words, such as:

```
var dictionary = new List<string>()
{
    "clock",
    "block",
    "crock",
    "black",
};
```

And can express the current guess as a `char?[]`, like this:

```
var guess = new char?[] { null, 'L', 'O', null, 'K' };
```

Then the method to find matching words is easily done like this:

```
var matches =
    dictionary
        .Select(word => word.ToUpperInvariant())
        .Where(word => word.Zip(guess, (w, g) => g == null || w == g).All(x => x))
        .ToList();
```

This computes:

```
CLOCK 
BLOCK
```